# Are there alternatives functions for the gamma function that was used as generalisation for the factorials?

Tags: mathematics, real-analysis

I asked this question on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4884328/are-there-alternatives-functions-for-the-gamma-function-that-was-used-as-general)

> $$\Gamma(x)= \int_0^ \infty e^{-t}t^{x-1}dt \ \ \ \  \  x>0.  $$

Bohr and Mollerup showed that the gamma  function is the only positive  function $f$ defined on $(0,\infty)$ that has these properties

1. $f(x+1)=xf(x)$
2. $f(1)=1$
3. $f(x)$ is a continuous
4. $f(x)$  is log convex

But before Bohr and Mollerup  why did Euler or Bernoulli  chose this function ? there are infinite many  positive continuous function $f$ st $f(x+1)=xf(x)$, was there any alternatives functions for the gamma function as a generalisation for the factorials  that was used before and now we stopped? If there is one then why do we stop using it? If there isn't one then  how did Euler and other found the "Only" "natural" generalisation  for the factorials centuries before   Bohr and Mollerup as somehow they knew that this solution is unique and why $\Gamma$
stands out from other options.

Comment: Euler did not "choose" because he had nothing to choose from, see [Davis](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Davis.pdf). In the 18th century, "function" meant analytic formula, so he played around with infinite products and found one that interpolated the factorial. Alternatives have more complex analytic expressions and did not come up. Appearance of $\pi$ for half-integers suggested integrals similar to those for the circle area, which he then transformed into a form of the $\Gamma$ integral. Not the OP one, that one was derived from his later by Legendre.

Comment: By mid-19th century one could trivially write down alternatives by adding to $\Gamma$ a function that vanishes on all integers ([Weierstrass factorization theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem) constructs such analytic functions as modified infinite products), but there was little point to the exercise. The result is more complicated than $\Gamma$, and $\Gamma$ had many connections to other functions of interest, aside from interpolating the factorial, to be singled out anyway.

Comment: @Conifold " but there was little point to the exercise. The result is more complicated than $\Gamma$
, and $\Gamma$
 had many connections to other functions of interest," can you give some examples ?

Comment: @pie Not my area of expertise, but you may enjoy reading the following [account](https://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunction.html): Peter Luschny, "Is the Gamma function mis-defined? Or: Hadamard versus Euler - Who found the better Gamma function?"

Comment: [*Leonhard Euler's integral: a historical profile of the gamma function*](https://maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Chauvenet/Davis.pdf) by Philip J. Davis (1959) is freely available and might be useful for what you're interested in. Incidentally, regarding the comment about the gamma function being a transcendentally transcendental function (bottom half of p. 864), see [this MSE answser](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/55016/13130).

Comment: I just noticed (over an hour later) that @Conifold had already cited the Davis paper. I did read the previous comments before writing mine, but I had missed the "see Davis" part at the end of his first comment's first sentence.

Comment: This question that you asked on MSE has some nice answers in the comments there. Why don't they satisfy you?

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko These comments were posted under the Mse question after I posted this question here , but they answer my question